# Error import functions inside another function when pressing button

Tags: python-3.x

I have a problem with importing a function, so far everything worked fine for me until I did the validate function and called it from the button, why am I getting this error?

Main.py

```
Python
Expand ▼   
class AplicacionInventario:

    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.title("StockMaster")
        self.root.geometry("400x500")
        #Bloquear agrandar ventana
        self.root.resizable(0,0)

        self.wtotal = self.root.winfo_screenwidth()
        self.htotal = self.root.winfo_screenheight()
        #  Guardamos el largo y alto de la ventana
        self.wventana = 400
        self.hventana = 500
        # #  Aplicamos la siguiente formula para calcular donde debería posicionarse
        self.pwidth = round(self.wtotal/2-self.wventana/2)
        self.pheight = round(self.htotal/2-self.hventana/2)
        #  Se lo aplicamos a la geometría de la ventana
        self.root.geometry(str(self.wventana)+"x"+str(self.hventana)+"+"+str(self.pwidth)+"+"+str(self.pheight))

        self.imagen = Image.open("src/logo.png")
        self.imagen = self.imagen.resize((350, 100))  # Opcional: Redimensionar la imagen
        self.imagen = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.imagen)
        # Crear un widget Label con la imagen y colocarlo en la ventana
        self.label_imagen = tk.Label(self.root, image=self.imagen)
        self.label_imagen.pack(pady=20)

        #self.login1 = login(self)
        self.prueba = login(self)


        #fetch_data_button = tk.Button(self.root, text="Obtener Datos", command=self.mostrar2)
        #fetch_data_button.pack()
        

        self.root.mainloop()

AplicacionInventario()
```

loggin.py

```
Python
Expand ▼   
def login(self):
        self.t_Email = "Email:"
        self.label_email = tk.Label(self.root, text=self.t_Email)
        self.label_email.pack(pady=5, padx=20)
        self.label_email.place(x=150, y=150, width=100, height=20)
        
        self.entry_email = tk.Entry(self.root)
        self.entry_email.pack(pady=5)
        self.entry_email.place(x=75, y=170, width=250, height=50)
        
        self.t_Password = "Contraseña:"
        self.label_password = tk.Label(self.root, text=self.t_Password)
        self.label_password.pack(pady=5, padx=20)
        self.label_password.place(x=150, y=220, width=100, height=20)
        
        self.entry_password = tk.Entry(self.root, show="*")
        self.entry_password.pack(pady=5)
        self.entry_password.place(x=75, y=240, width=250, height=50)
        
        self.login_email = self.entry_email.get()
        self.login_password = self.entry_password.get()
        
        self.boton_login = tk.Button(self.root, text="Iniciar Sesión", command=self.validar)
        self.boton_login.pack(pady=5)
        self.boton_login.place(x=125, y=300, width=150, height=50)

def validar(self):
    self.conexion_login = connect_to_database()
    self.cursor_conexion_login = self.conexion_login.cursor()

    self.cursor_conexion_login.execute("SELECT email, password FROM usuarios WHERE email=%s AND password=%s", (self.login_email, self.login_password))
    self.verificar_login = self.cursor_conexion_login.fetchone()
```

ERROR:

```
Python
<pre>raceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tomassanchezgarcia/Desktop/python-test/main.py", line 64, in <module>
    AplicacionInventario()
  File "/Users/tomassanchezgarcia/Desktop/python-test/main.py", line 38, in __init__
    self.prueba = login(self)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/tomassanchezgarcia/Desktop/python-test/iniciar_sesion.py", line 31, in login
    self.boton_login = tk.Button(self.root, text="Iniciar Sesión", command=self.validar)
                                                                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'AplicacionInventario' object has no attribute 'validar'
```

What I have tried:

Hello, I have a problem with importing a function, so far everything worked fine for me until I did the validate function and called it from the button, why am I getting this error?

how can I solve that?

Any additional information would be appreciated.